# Java REST IE @DELETE 405 Method not allowed

Tags: java, rest

I'm writing a RESTService in Java. But it doesn't work in the Internet Explorer

```
@DELETE
@Path("/deleteData/{dataID}")
public Response deleteText(@PathParam("dataID") int dataID) {

    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;

    try {

    adminService.deleteText(idText);

        builder = Response.status(200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Map<String, String> responseObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
        responseObj.put("error", e.getMessage());
        builder = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(
                responseObj);
    }

    return builder.build();
```

The AdminService delete the Text in the Database. With the Restclient AddOn in Firefox it works perfectly, if I choose DELETE. But the Internet Explorer tells me "405 method not allowed". How can I change that?

Comment: Does it matter? Are your users going to use the webservice through a browser?:)

Comment: How do you send DELETE request with IE?

Comment: By calling: http://localhost:9080/deleteText/1
1 is the ID

Answer (score 3):

If you only use something like http://localhost/deleteData/123 on IE, ie will send a GET request, hence the error 405. That's why it's working in Restclient AddOn since you specify the method of the call.